# Why is memory_order given as a runtime argument to std::atomic functions

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic, memory-model

`std::atomic` functions such as `store` and `load` take an `std::memory_order` argument. The argument can be determined at runtime, like any other function argument. However, the actual value may effect the optimization of the code during compilation. Consider the following:

```
std::atomic<int> ai1, ai2;
int value = whatever;

void foo() {
    std::memory_order memOrd = getMemoryOrder();
    register int v = value; // load value from memory
    ai1.store(v, memOrd);   // dependency on v's value
    ai2.store(1, memOrd);   // no dependency. could this be move up?
}
```

If `memOrd` happens to be `memory_order_relaxed`, the second store could safely be moved in front of the first one. This will add some extra work between loading `value` and using it, which might prevent otherwise required stalls. However, if `memOrd` is `memory_order_seq_cst`, switching the stores should not be allowed, because some other thread might count on `ai1` being already set to `value` if `ai2` is set to 1.

What I'm wondering is why was the memory order defined as a runtime argument rather than compile time. Is there any reason for someone to examine the environment at runtime before deciding the best memory operations semantics?

Comment: Consider this only a hint. If the value is not actually a compile-time constant, the implementation may very well just use sequential consistency and never think about it twice.

Comment: Working from the answers given below: the reason was to give flexibility.  Any compiler daring to optimize around atomics will have no trouble tracking an argument in the cases worth optimizing.  Arguments for memory ordering are much easier to work with than template arguments, so why do the hard thing when you can do the easy thing!   (Also to be considered is that these functions correspond to C equivalent functions... and those are easiest implemented with memory order arguments)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *reason* this is implemented as a runtime parameter rather than a compile-time parameter is to enable composition.

Suppose you are writing a function that uses the provided atomic operations to do the equivalent of a *load* operation, but operating on a higher level construct. By having the memory order specified as a runtime parameter the higher level load can then pass a memory order parameter supplied by the user to the low-level atomic operation that is required to provide the ordering without the higher level operation having to be a template.

Typically, the atomic instructions will be inline, and the compiler will eliminate the test of the memory order parameter in the case that it is actually a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 4):

It's just an interface specification that *allows* the `memory_order` to be specified at runtime. It doesn't require the implementation to use that allowance.

For example, on x86 hardware `memory_order_seq_cst` is probably what you get, whatever you specify. `memory_order_relaxed` just isn't available because of the hardware cache coherency protocol.

On other hardware, where you might be able to optimize for compile time known order, the implementation might offer additional overloads that take advantage of the default parameters.

Comment: The hardware coherence protocol is just half of the story. Unless I'm missing something, you should benefit from relaxed order (given correct algorithm) even when targeting x86, because it allows compiler optimizations like the one I describe in my question. If the interface doesn't provide the compiler enough information, you do end up relying only on the hardware, and loosing potential compile-time gain. It just seemed like a strange design choice, given you do know everything you need at compile time. Or don't you?...

Comment: The compiler *will* know if the value is a compile time constant (or you use the default parameter value), and can optimize according to that. I'm sure they will in cases where this is important.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Are you sure the x86 memory model is equivalent to `memory_order_seq_cst`? I always thought it only guarantees `memory_order_acq_rel`.

Comment: And regarding optimization: The people writing the standard library are not necessarily the same who write the compiler. I sure *hope* that all relevant compilers will get this right, but I wouldn't bet on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The writers of C++ could have implemented memory_order as a compile time feature, rather than a runtime feature.  However, they would not have gained anything for it.  Any compiler capable of comprehending memory orders is going to easily optimize the obvious cases like x.load(memory_order_acq), so they would not benefit from it being a compile time feature.

Meanwhile, using a runtime feature means they did not have to introduce any new notation for memory orders.  They're just function arguments.  This means they gained the same benefits as the compile time version, with less complexity.

Meanwhile, it is very convenient for simpler compilers, because they can implement atomic as a normal class, without having to treat it specially.

```
T atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong(T& compare, T exchange, memory_order order)
{
    lockBeforeUsing(order); // handle the acquire part of the memory order
    if (mValue == compare) {
        compare = mValue;
        mValue = compare;
    } else {
        compare = mValue;
    }
    lockAfterUsing(order); // handle the release part of the memory order
}
```

Comment: They wouldn't need to introduce new notation anyway. They could've just made it a template parameter.