Is `std::memory_order` a special tag for compilers at the compile time?
The arguments of type std::memory_order passed to atomic operation affect compile-time and runtime. However, I wonder if this type is a special tag for the compiler. In other words, when given the user-defined type with the same values, for example
#include <atomic>
enum my_memory_order{
    release = (int)std::memory_order::release,
};
int main(){
    std::atomic<int> v = {0};
    v.store(1,(std::memory_order)my_memory_order::release);  // #1
}

Is the user-defined enumeration my_memory_order recognized by the compiler and emits the same code at the compile-time as if the passed argument was std::memory_order::release? Or, std::memory_orders are special tags privileged by compilers?

Another question is, how does the compiler know whether the code should be reordered according to the supplied std::memory_order? For example:
void show(std::memory_order){
  /// balabala
}
int main(){
   int x;
   std::memory_order ordering; 
   ordering = /*runtime value*/;
   x = 1;
   show(ordering);
}

Does the compiler see this function has some arguments with type std::memory_order, so it will emit some branch to generate the code according to reordering semantics?

Related if not a dupe, at least you can find the answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941136/why-is-memory-order-given-as-a-runtime-argument-to-stdatomic-functions

Unfortunately the [memory-order] is a tag-synonym of [memory-barriers], rather than the other way around.  Despite general agreement with my meta suggestion (Reverse the [memory-barriers] [memory-order] synonym situation so questions about C++ std::memory_order can be tagged memory-order, not barriers), it hasn't been fixed.  I added the tag anyway.

If inlining fails to prove what memory order is being used by a given atomic operation (or indeed that no atomic operations exist), the obvious answer is always to not reorder.

We can see what happens when you hide the value of the order from the compiler.
volatile std::memory_order ord;
void my_store(std::atomic<int>& dest, int val)
{
    std::memory_order ord_copy = ord;
    dest.store(val, ord_copy);
}

On GCC version 13.2.0, it compiles to the following:
my_store(std::atomic<int>&, int):
        adrp    x2, .LANCHOR0
        ldr     w2, [x2, #:lo12:.LANCHOR0]
        stlr    w1, [x0]
        ret
ord:
        .zero   4

It takes the approach of just using the most conservative option. MSVC takes a different approach since it issues a memory barrier when sequential consistency is specified (not a bug since the standard says that despite the name, sequential consistency still only uses acquire/release semantics).
        ;ARM64

|std::memory_order volatile ord| % 0x4                    ; ord

|void my_store(std::atomic<int> &,int)| PROC            ; my_store
        adrp        x8,|std::memory_order volatile ord|
        ldr         w9,[x8,|std::memory_order volatile ord|]
        cmp         w9,#5
        bhi         |$LN8@my_store|
        adr         x10,__swt
        ldrsb       x8,[x10,w9 uxtw #0]
        add         x8,x10,x8,lsl #2
        br          x8
|$LN6@my_store|
        str         w1,[x0]
        ret
|$LN7@my_store|
        stlr        w1,[x0]
        ret
|$LN8@my_store|
        stlr        w1,[x0]
        dmb         ish
        ret
|__swt|
|$LN25@my_store|
        DCB         0xf9
|$LN26@my_store|
        DCB         0xfd
|$LN27@my_store|
        DCB         0xfd
|$LN28@my_store|
        DCB         0xfb
|$LN29@my_store|
        DCB         0xfd
|$LN30@my_store|
        DCB         0xfd
|$LN31@my_store|
        DCB         0xfd
|$LN32@my_store|
        DCB         0xfd

        ENDP  ; |void my_store(std::atomic<int> &,int)|, my_store

The important part that the other compilers aren't doing is that the stlr instruction is sufficient for store/release semantics. However, for sequential consistency, you need that additional dmb ish instruction which issues a full memory barrier. It also shows an alternative approach where it branches depending on the runtime value of the memory ordering.
